# How to display Vim "bang" output below editor window instead of popping out to terminal?

Tags: vim, terminal

Numerous sources indicate that running a "bang" command such as `:! wc %` will display the results in Vim below the editor window. (For instance, [this tip sheet](https://www.linux.com/learn/vim-tips-working-external-commands) states that as the expected behavior.)

Specifically, I'm following along with [this Vimcast tutorial](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim---a-complement-to-command-line-git/) on Tim Pope's Fugitive plugin, and in that Drew Neil states that running the `:Git` command will allow the user to run any arbitrary git command from inside Vim--and the output of the command will be displayed within Vim at the bottom of the screen.

This is *not* the behavior I am experiencing. Instead my Vim session is in essence sent to the background, and I'm popped back to my terminal to see the output. It's all very disorienting--specifically because I lose the useful visual context provided by my Vim session including the "bang" command that generated the output.

I'd love it if Vim actually did display the externally generated output in Vim below the editor window. I found some [similar types of questions](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window), but in all of them the user wanted to output the content to a new buffer rather than just see it momentarily printed at the bottom of the editor window. In other words, I've not found anyone else describing the behavior I'm seeing.

I was able to get the desired behavior in gVim, but gVim isn't always a viable option, so I'd like to know whether there is a broader solution that will allow the expected behavior in terminal-based Vim.

I'm using Vim 8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. My terminal is gnome-terminal with the zsh shell. I tried some other terminals on my machine and the bash shell, and I'm experiencing this behavior regardless of which combination I use.

Here are two screenshots that demonstrate the behavior I'm seeing. On the left is a terminal-based Vim, and on the right is gVim. Notice how running `:! wc %` has the expected/desired behavior in gVim on the right, but not in regualar Vim on the left.

Screenshot before running command:

[image: screenshot before running command]

Screenshot after running command:

[image: screenshot after running command]

Is anyone else experiencing this? Does anyone else get the desired behavior from their terminal-based Vim? (Perhaps this is all some kind of documentation oversight and terminal-based Vim was never expected to behave in the desired way?)

Thanks!

Comment: `:r! command` will read the command output and insert the output to cursor position of current buffer.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution in one of the similar types of question that I linked to in my question. This doesn't seem equivalent to momentarily displaying it at the bottom of the screen because I'd have to undo the the output that was written into my current buffer (or if I sent it to a new buffer in a split or tab, then I'd need to delete the buffer it was sent to).

Comment: It seems you want to show external command output  on quickfix window. I also searched it long time ago,but can not find a good solution to it. vim only allow limited commands, such as make or grep to output to quickfix window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's GVim (or MacVim) that shows the output of external command at the bottom of the window because it comes with a *very* minimal terminal emulator. Plain Vim is incapable of doing that.

You could emulate that behavior with tmux via any of the many Vim plugins that provide tmux integration or, since you are using Vim 8.0, the new built-in `:help :terminal` emulator.

For your example:

```
:term wc %
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this new feature in Vim 8.0, I have tested it on  Vim 8.0, It works, By the way, the short format of `:terminal` command is `:ter`, not `:term`

Comment: Ah, thanks for confirming it's a gVim/MacVim feature. Makes sense since Drew Neil appears to use MacVim and his vimcasts are one of the primary ways I learned about Vim features.


`:term wc %` definitely worked better than being popped out to the terminal with the "bang" command. Thanks for that tip! (Too bad it won't work for plugin commands with terminal output like `:Glog` from the Fugitive plugin`. Still, better than nothing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that I stumbled across is to use AsyncRun from [this plugin](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim). It acts as alternative to the shebang command, runs the command in the background, and sends the output to the quickfix window.

While I still think the accepted answer is the right one (i.e. that a TUI Vim always outputs to the terminal shell instead of the internal shell), someone else coming across this thread might find AsyncRun to be a better alternative to "that's just how it works".

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a easy solution by chance while making a typo:

`:w !wc %`

Use the `:w` command before `!` and it will display the results of the shell command (the command following the !) in Vim below the editor window even in Plain Vim (I am using VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0).

Some example use-case:
`:w !clang % -o %<&&./%<` or `:w !gcc %&&./a.out`
will compile/execute the current C file (display the result of executing the C program) below the editor waiting for you to press enter. It is a very neat workflow. Use the `:make` command if you have a project with more than one file.

- `!` will execute a shell command from VIM.
- `%` is the name of the current file open in VIM.
- `&&` is logical AND, it will let you chain multiple commands.
- `<` will remove the extension of the file so `%<` is the name of the current file without extension.

PS: I am not sure why this work or even if it is good practice, I only viewed the `:w` for saving file prior to this discovery, if any one can enlighten me in comment I will be delighted.